# SQL error:8152, but not over max?

Tags: sql, jboss, seam, zk

I'm part of a team writing an ERP using , Seam, and Jboss, and on one of my pages, I keep getting an SQL error: 8152 whenever I try to input something. SQL error:8152, for those of you who don't know, is when you try to input a value over the maximum limit of the column.

I've double checked my entity and the database, and their maximum value limits are the same (50 nvarchars). In addition, I'm pretty sure that we're not using audit tables. I then put System.out.println(""); all over the place, and found that the error was happening in between these two println(s):

```
            System.out.println("Flushing");
        entityManager.flush();
        System.out.println("Flushing complete");
```

Which is part of a method that process all changes to the table. But I'm pretty new to programming and not sure what's going on.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance, Jeff.

P.s. Code on request, but I didn't post it because there is a lot of it all over the place.

Comment: flush() forces a write of all pending database changes to database, so it might be that any other related entity throws the exception. Please carefully study your exception stack.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify the SQL that is being executed when the flush() is performed.  That way you can see the length of your data and verify that it is too big as shown by the DB error.

If you are using Hibernate, you can output SQL to the console.  You don't say what your DB is, but if it's SQL Server you can use the profiler to see what SQL is being executed.